# z-index and Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, iframe, internet-explorer-9, z-index

I've got 2 elements, 2 images of exactly the same dimensions, positioned one on top of the other. Say they're called A and B (A is the top one). What I've done is made it so when you hover over A, its z-index decrements by 2 so that B is now on top, and B's hover: increments its z-index by 2 so it's now higher by 1 than A's original z-index (thus image B stays on top until you remove mouse). So basically...

```
#A {z-index: 5;}
#B {z-index: 4;}

#A:hover {z-index: 3;}
#B:hover {z-index: 6;}
```

This works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but IE doesn't want to hear about it, and my images keep spazzing while hovering over them. Any help is appreciated. Positioning is Absolute, if that matters.

@jklm313

That actually works in my IE9 as well. Maybe I should post the full code since one of my "images" is actually a social network button. So here it is:

HTML:

```
<div id="myTweetBrown"></div>
<div id="myTweet"><?php include ("myPHP/homepageSoc/tweet.php") ?></div>
```

CSS:

```
#myTweetBrown {
position: absolute;
background-image: url('../images/tweetBrown.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
height: 20px;
width: 54px;
left: 381px;
top: 662px;
z-index: 5;
}

#myTweetBrown:hover {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
}

#myTweet {
position: absolute;
height: 20px;
width: 54px;
left: 381px;
top: 662px;
z-index: 4;
}

#myTweet:hover {
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
}
```

tweet.php:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://localhost/Joomla173/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=69&amp;Itemid=507" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Link to demo website: *************  -- scroll down to Tweet button
This will be up only for so long, because I don't want people to have access like that <.<

Comment: Sounds a lot like http://jhop.me/tests/bugs/ie8/dynamicstackingcontext.html - http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs number 56.

Answer (score 2):

Just going to rewrite my whole answer now the source code has been provided.

All "modern" versions of IE, when not in quirks mode, accept this code perfectly fine for divs and links. The problem in IE arises for iframes and other unusual elements, at which point its rendering engine seems to fail. *(Shock!)* You'll get this flickering for no apparent reason, except perhaps the conflicting doctypes in the iframe and page, which I would also try avoid if possible.

Presuming this link is generated by twitter, I would advise a fallback approach for IE. Instead of hovering between your button image and a twitter provided button image, I would just manipulate the css of the button twitter provided inside the iframe using javascript.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className += 'myTweetBrown';
```

The button looks to be generated by HTML5 rather than being a static image, so it shouldn't be difficult to manipulate:

```
.myTweetBrown:hover {
    background-image: url('../images/tweetBrown.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    width: 55px !important;
 }

.myTweetBrown:hover * {
    display: none;
 }
```

The other approach you could take is keep doing what you were doing before, but applying the styles differently like so, dependant on display:

```
#myTweetBrown {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('../images/tweetBrown.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 20px;
    width: 54px;
    left: 381px;
    top: 662px;
    z-index: 5;
}

#myTweetBrown:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#myTweet {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 54px;
    left: 381px;
    top: 662px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: this code is the same as mine, but it doesn't work for me. Element b can't retain the hover state for some reason, apparently. At least for me...

Comment: There must be something else interfering on the page, could you link us to a demo site?

Comment: I can, I will edit my first post and post the link in a moment.

Comment: You've got an iframe in there? I think that's causing the issue - remove the iframe and it seems to work as intended.

Comment: I can't because that is the twitter button code which I copied off of twitter web =/

Comment: Can you not just embed the button code it directly into the page? Why does it need to be shown through an iframe?

Comment: actually now that I'm looking at the source, I don't see the iframe? And I did embed the button code directly into the page.

Comment: body > #wrapper > #container > #content_out > #maincontent > .item_page_test > #startpos > #hoverer > #mytweet > iframe

Comment: Apparently the button automatically adds this code. There's nothing I can do about it. Oh well. I guess I'll just use a different CSS for IE which won't have the brown image over the regular button. Thanks for the help anyway =)

Comment: Updated again, I hope this approach works. Nothing simple you can do for IE people without javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Technically, CSS doesn't actually specify how and when elements go in and out of the "hover" state. So it sounds like when A goes under B, your version of IE removes the hover state from A and it immediately pops back in front of B, before B gets the hover state and pops further in front.

How about wrapping the two in a div, and testing for the hover state on that? Does that work?

http://jsfiddle.net/X64au/

Comment: nope, it works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE. =/ Thanks, though.

Comment: Was worth a shot. The tweet button javascript could be doing all sorts of mischief, I guess.

Comment: That should happen when the element is hovered over initially, but then the b element should retain the hover state while the mouse remains over it, so there should be no "spazzing" except a flicker when the mouse is first moved over the elements.

Comment: Exactly. But for some reason it acts as if b:hover just doesn't exists so it keeps constantly flickering.

Comment: The twitter code is creating a 'lovely' iframe for the button... I have a feeling that might have something to do with the issue, just by looking at a google search for iframe z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap them in a div

```
.parent
{
   position:relative;
   z-index:1000;
}
.a
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index : 1001;
  display: inline-block;
}
.b
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1002;
  display: inline-block;
}
```